# Sending encrypted data via TCP (“Bad Data” exception)

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, tcp, decoding

How can i send illegal charecters from tpc client to tcp server.
This is an example of what the encrypted gibberish looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfZdm.png

How can i send this pice of gibberish to either my client or server?

This is my encryption & decryption code

```
public static string Decrypt(string data)
        {
            byte[] dataToDecrypt = StringToByteArray(data);

            byte[] decryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
                decryptedData = rsa.Decrypt(dataToDecrypt, false);
            }

            UnicodeEncoding byteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
            return ByteArrayToString(decryptedData);
        }

        public static string Encrypt(string data, string publicKey)
        {
            UnicodeEncoding byteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] dataToEncrypt = StringToByteArray(data);

            byte[] encryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
                encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
            }
            return ByteArrayToString(encryptedData);
        }


public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string data)
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] bytes)
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        }
```

I have made it so the client and the server share eachothers public keys but i am getting Exception "Bad data". One more thing if i send encrypted data from a client to the server which data is 128 bytes the server receives only 78 bytes for example

Comment: There are no "illegal characters" in TCP. In fact, TCP doesn't care about text encoding at all. I think you're misunderstanding what text encoding does.

Comment: I have made it so the client and the server share eachothers public keys but i am getting Exception "Bad data". One more thing if i send encrypted data from a client to the server which data is 128 bytes the server receives only 78 bytes for example.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you want to send "gibberish", what's stopping you? Why not just pick some random bytes (the .NET `Random` class conveniently has a method to do exactly that) and transmit them. The bytes may or may not be valid text, but they'd definitely be "gibberish".

Comment: How are you sending a `String` to a `Socket`, exactly? You should be working **only** with `Byte[]` buffers when doing network programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your code:

- You shouldn't be using `String` at all.

  - `String` is meant for text, not arbitrary binary data (I assume you got this impression from C or PHP where their string types are really just synonyms for - or thin-wrappers over - a byte-array).
- Keep the `Byte[]` buffer you get from `rs.Encrypt` and pass that directly to your `Socket`, `TcpClient` or `NetworkStream` that you're using. You'll need to define a binary protocol with length-prefix though.
- `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` will convert the UTF-16LE-encoded characters in the `String data` instance to 7-bit ASCII, [it does this by replacing characters with values above `0x7F`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.ascii?view=netframework-4.8) with `'?'` - **this is not what you want!** (and this is what's causing the garbage output on your screen: those "illegal characters" are byte-values above `0x7F` that are outside ASCII's 7-bit range. From the documentation:

  > It uses replacement fallback to replace each string that it cannot encode and each byte that it cannot decode with a question mark ("?") character.
- If you really do want to transmit data over the network using human-readable text then use Base64 encoding: `Convert.ToBase64String( Byte[] buffer )` and convert it back using `Convert.FromBase64String( String s )` at the receiving end - but you'll still need to length-prefix or delimit your data.